# How to fix wrong path for FileInputStream and FileDescriptor in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, fileinputstream, parcelfiledescriptor

FILE is created using URI in cacheDir but when i tried to get the path, image is not found, Logged the URI before creating file and able to see proper URI for image file. Now i had created a File in app cache and tried to retrieve the path of image then not getting full image path, Not sure image is created or not here is my code

```
 val imagesList = data?.extras?.getStringArray(GligarPicker.IMAGES_RESULT)
                if (!imagesList.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    val arrayList = ArrayList<MultipartBody.Part>()
                    for (i in 0 until imagesList.size) {
                        Log.e("imagesList.item", imagesList[i])
                        val uri = Uri.parse("file://" + imagesList[i].toString())
                        Log.e("URI", uri.toString())
                        val parcelFileDescriptor: ParcelFileDescriptor? =
                            requireContext().contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "r")
                        val fileDescriptor: FileDescriptor? = parcelFileDescriptor?.fileDescriptor

                        val file = File(
                            requireContext().cacheDir,
                            requireContext().contentResolver.getFileName(uri!!)
                        )
                        Log.e("File", file.path.toString())

                        val inputStream = FileInputStream(fileDescriptor)
                        val outputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
                        inputStream.copyTo(outputStream)

                        // creates RequestBody instance from file

                        val requestFile: RequestBody =
                            RequestBody.create("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull(), file)
                        // requireContext().create("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull(), file)

                        val body: MultipartBody.Part? =
                            MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.name, requestFile)

                        if (body != null) {
                            arrayList.add(body)
                        }
                    }
```

Tried to log the URI and FILEPATH ,Here is details

```
URI: file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20210131_150237.jpg
File: /data/user/0/com.visilogix.smarttrax/cache
```

Error logs

```
  Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.visilogix.smarttrax/cache: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:496)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:186)
    at com.visilogix.smarttrax.ui.performPutAway.GrnLinesFragment.onActivityResult(GrnLinesFragment.kt:283)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:170)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8110)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4838)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4886) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
 Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
    at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
```

Updated code for creating file

```
  val uri = Uri.parse("file://" + imagesList[i].toString())
                    Log.e("URI", uri.toString())
                    val parcelFileDescriptor: ParcelFileDescriptor? =
                        requireContext().contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "r")
                    val fileDescriptor: FileDescriptor? = parcelFileDescriptor?.fileDescriptor

                    val uri1 = Uri.parse(imagesList[i].toString())
                    Log.e("File", requireContext().contentResolver.getFileName(uri1!!))
                    val file = File(
                        requireContext().externalCacheDir?.path,
                        requireContext().contentResolver.getFileName(uri1!!)
                    )
                    file.parentFile.mkdir()
                    file.createNewFile()
                    Log.e(
                        "File2",
                        requireContext().contentResolver.getFileName(uri1!!).toString()
                    )

                    val inputStream = FileInputStream(fileDescriptor)
                    val outputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
                    inputStream.copyTo(outputStream)
```

App is crashing at `val outputStream = FileOutputStream(file)`.

```
 Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.visilogix.smarttrax/cache: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:496)
```

Comment: The message tells you that you try to open a directory instead of a file. Probably you created the directory with file.mkdirs() before you changed that to file.getParentFile().mkdirs();.

Comment: @blackapps file.mkdirs()  added but no luck

Comment: You should not have tried that of course. Please reread my message and delete the directory. Or use another name.

Comment: `requireContext().contentResolver.getFileName(uri1!!)` We cannot see which file name that would be or if it is empty. Please use a hard coded file name. Also tell the value of file.getAbsolutePath().

Comment: filepath recieved from imagePicker is : /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20210131_150237.jpg

By using this tried to create file as shown above

Comment: A normal image picker does not give such a file system path but a content scheme uri. But i ment not that one of course. Of the one you try to create. Of the one you have problems with.

Comment: By using this  /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20210131_150237.jpg only i had tried to create file , getAbsolutePath is crashing as file is not found

Comment: `requireContext().externalCacheDir?.path` That will not give you that path which you now mentioned twice. Read what i asked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229283/discussion-between-sri-and-blackapps).

Comment: @blackapps read your comment and tried it , I had mentioned details in chat. Could you please come to chat in above link

Comment: I will not chat.

Comment: Hard coded file name and File absolute path returning : /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<packagename>/cache

Answer (score 1):

Using "externalCacheDir" instead of "cacheDir" while creating file might solve the problem.

```
requireContext().externalCacheDir?.let {
            val file = File(
                    it.path,
                    requireContext().contentResolver.getFileName(uri!!)
            )
            file.createNewFile()

        }
```

Comment: Didn't fix it. here is path of file using externalCacheDir :  /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.visilogix.smarttrax/cache

Comment: Sorry, I have missed "getPath()" calling  in "requireContext().externalCacheDir". Calling  "requireContext().externalCacheDir.path" creates file and I am getting proper URI.

Comment: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.visilogix.smarttrax/cache: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)  facing the same issue with updated changes

Comment: Ok if this not working, Could you please help me with creating file using URI in kotlin

Comment: try with "file.createNewFile()" just after creating the file, because file is not getting created due to no content is available.

Comment: Could you please see the updated code at bottom of my question

Comment: Sorry did not get your query creating file using URI ?? I mean if you know URI that means file has been already created. Do you mean copying a file uri from different app to your app private folder ?

Comment: Those are selected images URIs from image picker , Now i want to get those images to app private folder ( i'm sending these images to server using multi part)

Comment: You could do one thing, if you are not saving images to your local database, then direct send byte array to server. Are you using OkHttp ?

Comment: I'm using retrofit multi part ( yes OkHttp) , No local DB .

Comment: I am achieving uploading image to php server using below code. I use Coroutine and Lambda expression which follows best practises. If you want then I can share.

Comment: If you are using multipart while sending images to server then please share details

Comment: Kindly check it out. I post this as another answer to this question. Good luck !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229280/discussion-between-nrusingha-moharana-and-sri).

Answer (score 1):

Sending image to php server using Okhttp:
First covert all images to byte array and put it in "backupData" list. Then call "backupOneByOne()" method.

```
private var client: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient()

init {
    client.setReadTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    client.setConnectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
}
val backupData: MutableList<ByteArray> = mutableListOf()

private suspend fun backupOneByOne(currentPosition: Int, byteArray: ByteArray) {
    val backupResponse = doBackupMultiPartData("merchantKey", byteArray)

    when (backupResponse) {
        is ResponseResult.Success -> {
            Log.d("nm==>>", "Menu Item backup successful !!! AND current item position= $currentPosition")
            if (currentPosition < backupData.size - 1) {
                backupOneByOne(currentPosition + 1, backupData[currentPosition + 1])
            } else {
                Log.d("nm==>>", "Backup of all items is done. Current position= $currentPosition")
            }
        }
        is ResponseResult.Error -> {
            Log.d("nm==>>", "Error while backup of Advance table : \n ${backupResponse.msg.errorMsg}")
        }
        else -> {
        }
    }
}
suspend fun doBackupMultiPartData(apiKey: String, imageData: ByteArray?): ResponseResult<ResponseWrapper<String>> {
    val requestBody = MultipartBuilder().type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
    //requestBody.addFormDataPart("id",2) put other form data fields
    if (imageData != null) {
        requestBody.addFormDataPart(
                "file", "Logo.png", RequestBody.create(
                MediaType.parse(
                        "image/png"
                ), imageData
        )
        )
    }

    val request = Request.Builder()
            .header("api_key", apiKey) // getting api key from backend
            .url("put url here....")
            .post(requestBody.build())
            .build()
    try {
        val result = apiRequest(request)
        Log.d("nm==>>", "Result: $result")
        return if (result != null) {
            val jsonObject = JSONObject(result)
            if (jsonObject.getBoolean("isSuccessful")) {
                ResponseResult.Success(ResponseWrapper("success", null))
            } else {
                ResponseResult.Error(
                        ResponseWrapper(null, "Back end code error: \n $result")
                )
            }
        } else {
            ResponseResult.Error(
                    ResponseWrapper(
                            null, "Getting NULL as result"
                    )
            )
        }
    } catch (jsonException: JSONException) {
        Log.d("nm==>>", "Restore JSON exception::: \n ${jsonException.localizedMessage}")
        return ResponseResult.Error(
                ResponseWrapper(
                        null,
                        "Restore Json Exception"
                )
        )
    } catch (exception: Throwable) {
        //Log.d("nm==>>", "Network exception::: \n ${exception.localizedMessage}")
        return ResponseResult.NoInternet
    }
}

private suspend fun apiRequest(request: Request): String? = suspendCancellableCoroutine { cancellableContinuation ->
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
        override fun onFailure(request: Request?, e: IOException?) {
            cancellableContinuation.resumeWith(Result.failure(Throwable("API failed.....${e?.localizedMessage}")))
        }

        override fun onResponse(response: Response?) {
            cancellableContinuation.resumeWith(Result.success(response?.body()?.string()))
        }
    })
}
sealed class ResponseResult<out T> {
    object Loading:ResponseResult<Nothing>()
    object Empty:ResponseResult<Nothing>()
    data class Success<T>(val result:T): ResponseResult<T>()
    data class Error<T>(val msg:T): ResponseResult<T>()
    object NoInternet:ResponseResult<Nothing>()
}
data class ResponseWrapper<out T>(val data: T?, val errorMsg: String?)
```